# How to get filepath value from the Json

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have a json file given below

```
var json={
   "AttachmentInfo":[  
      {  
         "FileName":"sign_encrypted_.pdf",
         "FilePath":"b89ddfa7-af16-4e4d-b16b-b6d49db9b91f",
         "FileSize":104504.0,
         "FileExtention":".pdf",
         "FileType":2
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to get the FilePath from the above json.

I tried

```
var filePath=(string)json["AttachmentInfo"].SelectToken("FilePath");
```

but only null value return.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to deserialize JSON and then you can access it like dynamic object, here is a snipe code:

```
string json = ...;
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
var filePath = obj.AttachmentInfo[0].FilePath;
```